# Delphi threads locks waits on strings operation

Tags: multithreading, delphi, wait, locks

There is a simple code:

```
  TParallel.For(1, 8,
    procedure(i: Integer)
    var
      localstr: String;
      Data: String;
      index: Integer;
    begin
      Data := 'test1 test2';
      index := 0;
      while true do
      begin
        index := index + 1;
        localstr := copy(Data, index, 1);
        if index > 2 then
          index := 0;
      end;
    end);
```

It should use 8 CPU cores but it only uses 1. The reason is the system procedure for clearing a `string` variable:

```
function _UStrClr(var S): Pointer;
```

```
if AtomicDecrement(P.refCnt) = 0 then
  FreeMem(P);
```

[`AtomicDecrement()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AtomicDecrement) applies a lock to make sure that the `string`'s reference count is not simultaneously decremented on different threads. But, I am absolutely sure that my `string`s are isolated inside the threads. Is there any way to tell `TParallel` not to do that?

I could use the classic low-level WinAPI calls, but that would lose the legacy code base.

Comment: Zornig the Hadgehogs, hrm? You can consider using [`SetThreadAffinityMask()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask) to run each thread on your favorite core.

Comment: I doubt that this is entriely the atomic reference counting operations. That would be the case if the string meta data with the reference count, for the different strings, were placed in the same 24 byte cache line. You might end up with some clashes there. But a far bigger issue surely is the memory allocation. It's well known that the default Delphi memory manager is not scalable. That's going to be your main problem I predict.

Answer (score 2):

> It should use 8 CPU cores

Just because you are creating 8 parallel loop iterations does not guarantee that each iteration will run on its own CPU core.  It is entirely possible that some will run on the same CPU core and the OS will have to task-switch between them.  Which CPU core a task runs on is up to the OS's thread scheduler.

> But, I am absolutely sure that my strings are isolated inside the threads.

*Your* use of the strings is isolated, but the compiler/RTL's use of the strings is not.  The underlying memory management is fairly thread-safe, and that means synchronizing access to a string's internal structure, *in case* multiple threads try to access a given string at the same time.

> Is there any way to tell `TParallel` not to do that?

No, and it is not `TParallel`'s fault to begin with. This is just how the RTL's internal management of `string`s is implemented in general.  If you don't like it, don't use reference-counted `string`s to begin with.

Comment: Isn't the non scalable heap allocator going to be the main issue here?

Comment: @Remy your assessment could not be more wrong - David is spot on. Put FastMM5 into the uses and watch that thing fly on 8 cores. That `Copy` line is causing a heap allocation and that bottlenecks in the memory manager.